# Hot Module Replacement with parcel for .elm files not working

Tags: elm, parceljs

I setup my first elm project with parcel for automatic rebuild and hmr, however, hmr is not working when I edit .elm files. It works if I change anything on the html or js side. Any hints?

Just did

```
npm install -g parcel-bundler
parcel index.html
```

Followed this guide - https://parceljs.org/elm.html

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "elm-hot": "^1.0.1",
    "node-elm-compiler": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Photo Groove</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://elm-in-action.com/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
import { Elm } from './PhotoGroove.elm';

Elm.PhotoGroove.init({
    node: document.getElementById('app')
});
```

Comment: How are you editing the Elm file? Check out [this section on configuring IDEs](https://parceljs.org/hmr.html#safe-write) to work with Parcel HMR.